# SQLite Select an id which is smaller than a number

Tags: sqlite, select

I am trying to only select the objects where the id is smaller than an int value.

e.g.: i have 3 objects -> id = 1, id = 2, id = 3
Now I want to only get the  objects with the id smaller than the variable i = 2;

How can I manage this?

```
sql = "SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id <= i";
```

Thanks ;-)

---

I am using SQLite3 on iPhone OS. When I do:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id <= 2
```

it works... but the problem is the variable i!

Comment: What language are you querying the database from?

Comment: what is your host language? sqlite itself isn't programmable in the manner you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supports standard SQL syntax for parameterized queries, so one of the following will be useful:

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id <= ?
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE id <= :i
```

The first uses a positional parameter (the `?`) and the second a named parameter (`i`). How those are bound in your host language we can't tell you; we don't know what lang you are using!

Comment: okay i got it ;-)

sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, i); 

worked for me ;-) THAAAANKS!!!!